# Handle exception like for each in lambda expression query

Tags: c#-4.0

```
var test3 = elList.Where(e => Convert.ToDateTime(e.Date, new CultureInfo("en-US", true)) <= 0).ToList();
```

Here i have used lambda expression feature of c#, my exact query is 
i need to handle exceptions for dates which cannot be converted to date time objects , but rest in the list should be added to result list.

i don't want use foreach loop like

```
elList.ForEach(item => { try{ Convert.ToDateTime(item.Date, new CultureInfo("en-US", true)) <= 0) } catch { } });
```

Comment: Hi Slaks,  Is there any way i can put try catch block inside my first code sample, i tried but could not, i did not get why microsoft has not provided the option

Comment: You can; you just need to return from a statement lambda.

Comment: i don't want write another method for that which returns, can i use anonymous methods inside that,please show some code sample

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use statement lambdas in LINQ methods:

```
elList.Where(e => { DateTime x; DateTime.TryParse(e, out x); return x; })
```